# JQuery popup not working after continuous call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 for my project and im trying to edit or display my data on popup.

When I call my open popup code 6 or 7 times I take javascript errors.

my controller is

```
    public ActionResult OpenEditForm(string objectParam, string formStatus)
    {
        BranchNotesDetailViewModel viewModel = new BranchNotesDetailViewModel();

        //..................

        return PartialView("Edit", viewModel);
    }
```

and my javascript code is

```
    myDialog = $("<div> </div>");

    function CreateDialog(name) {
        myDialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: name,
            resizable: false,
            position: 'center',
            stack: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            close: function (event, ui) {
                // remove div with all data and events
                myDialog.remove();
                //myDialog.dialog('close')
            }
        });
    }

    $('#brancNotesList .grid-row').click(function () {
        var json = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text().trim();
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/html',
            url: '@Url.Action("OpenEditForm", "BranchNotes")',
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                objectParam: json,
                formStatus: "1"
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
            CreateDialog('Detail');
            myDialog.html(result).dialog('open');
        });

    });

$(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        //re-parse the DOM after Ajax to enable client validation for any new form fields that have it enabled
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
    });
});

function openFormCreate() {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/html',
        url: '@Url.Action("OpenEditForm", "BranchNotes")',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            formStatus: '2'
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        CreateDialog('Detail');
        myDialog.html(result).dialog().dialog('open');
    });
}
```

When i open dialogs one or two times it works but after fifth or sixth time it crashes with exception 
JavaScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

I tried to find a memory problem or something after ajax call but i cant find where or what. Is there any way to handle that? I read about that problem some forums they say comments fields cause that but it not works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. I have two layouts, one for main page one for edit page and i noticed some Jquery script files rendered in both pages. I cleaned the edit layout from jquery scripts then everything works fine.